# Simple Harmonic Motion Question

Tags: kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, velocity, angular-velocity

I have two formulae:

Displacement = amplitude * sin(angular velocity * time)

Velocity = amplitude * angular velocity * cos(angular velocity * time)

Equivalently,

$x = A\sin(\omega t)$

$v = A\omega\cos(\omega t)$

And the question is using these two formulae show $v = \pm \omega\sqrt{A^2 - x^2}$

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is really a math question - or rather a math _problem_, since you haven't actually asked a question. It's not really about _physics_, though. Plus, it sounds a lot like a homework problem, and this is not a homework help site; we have a set of [guidelines](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) for asking questions of an educational nature, which require focusing on the concept that's giving you trouble, not just posting the question itself.

Comment: Sorry! You're right it was homework, albeit an extension question, but it was set by my physics teacher so I figured physics was the place to be. But thanks I'll read through the guidelines!

Comment: Thanks for understanding :-) As a general rule, basically you should "dig into" your problem at least enough to figure out whether it's the math or the physics that is really giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate $x^2 +\frac{v^2}{\omega ^2}$:

$x^2 + \frac{v^2}{\omega ^2}=A^2(\cos^2(\omega t) + \sin^2(\omega t) )$

$x^2+ \frac{v^2}{\omega ^2}=A^2$

$v^2=\omega ^2(A^2-x^2)$

Which gives us

$v=\pm \omega \sqrt{A^2-x^2}$